# Difference between 'union' and 'union all' when SQL-code grades at LMS platfrom

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I have problem with grading an exercise at LMS platform.

We have two queries:

```
select
    distinct c.city_name,'city' obj_type
from
    shipping.city c
union all
select
    distinct c.state,'state' obj_type
from
    shipping.city c
union all
select
    distinct d.first_name,'driver' obj_type
from
    shipping.driver d
union all
select
    distinct t.Make,'truck' obj_type
from
    shipping.truck t
order by 1 desc
```

and this:

```
select
    c.city_name,'city' obj_type
from
    shipping.city c
union
select
    c.state,'state' obj_type
from
    shipping.city c
union
select
    d.first_name,'driver' obj_type
from
    shipping.driver d
union
select
    t.Make,'truck' obj_type
from
    shipping.truck t
order by 1 desc
```

Both get me same results, but second don't grades at the platfrom. At the same time I check results with except in Metabase and it get me "No results!" (null)

How the platform works:

It send 2 queries to base and check the difference between student's and reference responses.

I thought that in Metabase there could be a ragged view of the data with 'union' and 'union all', but  comparison with except get me nothing.

Update: I solved the problem. There was a different sort in two queries; the platform checked for it too and the queries were different.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I don't understand, why one of two queries with identical result don't grades at platfrom correctly.

Comment: to check results use `EXCEPT ALL` instead of `EXCEPT`

Comment: Oh! I didn't know about nulls and exept all, thank you! I'll try that.

Comment: as I suggest in my answer, I think your problem is that you have same values in some column (for example two drivers with same name..), so result sets **ARE** different, but you see no difference because you use `EXCEPT` instead of `EXCEPT ALL`

Comment: @MtwStark : There can be no duplicates *between* the query parts, since the {city,state,driver,truck} literals will always be different.

Comment: @wildplasser what about two drivers or two cities with same name or two trucks with same make?

Comment: Point is: the query parts will always differ on `obj_type`. period.

Comment: Point are: 1) why LMS reject second query 2) why op doesn't see any difference using `EXCEPT`. The answer are 1) queries are different and their results are different as well 2) op uses `EXCEPT` instead of `EXCEPT ALL` . period .

Answer (score 0):

If you have rows in the same table **with the same value** or with `NULL`'s in `city_name` or `state` or `first_name` or `make` results may be different.

**EDIT:** Try to check your results with `EXCEPT ALL` instead of `EXCEPT` or you will not see all differences.

Take a look at this example:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (name VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (surname VARCHAR(10))

DECLARE @R1 TABLE (descr VARCHAR(10), typ VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @R2 TABLE (descr VARCHAR(10), typ VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT * 
FROM( VALUES ('Abigail'), ('Luke'), ('Mat'), ('Mat'), ('Zoe')) x (d)

INSERT INTO @T2
SELECT * 
FROM( VALUES ('Brown'), ('Doe'), ('Doe'), ('Smith'), ('Wilkinson')) x (d)

insert into @r1
select name descr, 'name' descr_type from @t1
union 
select surname descr, 'surname' descr_type from @t2

insert into @r2
select name descr, 'name' descr_type from @t1
union all
select surname descr, 'surname' descr_type from @t2

select * from @r1
select * from @r2
```

If you check results:

```
select * from @r1
except
select * from @r2
```

Will produce "No results!" (null)

```
select * from @r1
except all
select * from @r2
```

Will produce this result:

```
descr   typ
'Doe'   'surname'
'Mat'   'name'
```

If you want to see differences details:

```
select * 
    from 
        (select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by descr order by descr) n, * from @r1) r1
    full join 
        (select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by descr order by descr) n, * from @r2) r2 
    on r1.n= r2.n and r1.descr = r2.descr
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the three *legs* of the UNION will always be different, becaus of the different constants for the {city,state,driver,truck} literal. So, there will be no duplicates, and `UNION` yields the same result as `UNION ALL`.

Example:

---

```
        -- some data ...
CREATE TABLE one
        ( num integer not null
        , nam text
        );
INSERT INTO one ( num , nam ) values (1,'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three');

        -- QUERY#1
SELECT 'from_first' AS "origin"
        , num, nam
FROM one
UNION
SELECT 'from_second' AS "origin"
        , num, nam
FROM one
ORDER BY 1,2
        ;

        -- QUERY#2
SELECT 'from_first' AS "origin"
        , num, nam
FROM one
UNION ALL
SELECT 'from_second' AS "origin"
        , num, nam
FROM one
ORDER BY 1,2
        ;
```

---

Results:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
   origin    | num |  nam  
-------------+-----+-------
 from_first  |   1 | one
 from_first  |   2 | two
 from_first  |   3 | three
 from_second |   1 | one
 from_second |   2 | two
 from_second |   3 | three
(6 rows)

   origin    | num |  nam  
-------------+-----+-------
 from_first  |   1 | one
 from_first  |   2 | two
 from_first  |   3 | three
 from_second |   1 | one
 from_second |   2 | two
 from_second |   3 | three
(6 rows)
```

---

The situation is different when one or two of the subselects yield duplicates themselves, as in:

---

```
        -- some more data ...
CREATE TABLE two
        ( num integer not null
        , nam text
        );
INSERT INTO two ( num , nam ) values (1,'one'), (2, 'two'), (2, 'two');

        -- QUERY#1a
SELECT 'from_first' AS "origin"
        , num, nam
FROM two
UNION
SELECT 'from_second' AS "origin"
        , num, nam
FROM two
ORDER BY 1,2
        ;

        -- QUERY#2b
SELECT 'from_first' AS "origin"
        , num, nam
FROM two
UNION ALL
SELECT 'from_second' AS "origin"
        , num, nam
FROM two
ORDER BY 1,2
        ;
```

---

Results2:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
   origin    | num | nam 
-------------+-----+-----
 from_first  |   1 | one
 from_first  |   2 | two
 from_second |   1 | one
 from_second |   2 | two
(4 rows)

   origin    | num | nam 
-------------+-----+-----
 from_first  |   1 | one
 from_first  |   2 | two
 from_first  |   2 | two
 from_second |   1 | one
 from_second |   2 | two
 from_second |   2 | two
(6 rows)
```